# Signup form align to the right of the slider issue

Tags: html, css, slider

```css
form{
    max-width: 30%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 2%;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    color: black;
    font-family: fantasy;
}

.form-control{
    padding: 2%;
    margin: 1%;
    
}

label{
    border-radius: 4%;
    margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="six columns">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  
<!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="img/create.svg" alt="create">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       ....
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
    </div>
    

<div class="six columns">
    
  <form method="post" action="">
    
    <label>Your Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"><br />
        
        <label>Your Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control"><br />
    
    <label>Your Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control"><br />
        
        <label><input type="checkbox">Male</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox">Female</label>
        <button class="signin">Sign In</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

In home page I was trying to align slider and signup form. Slider should be on the left side and Sign up form is on the right. But Form is not moving up when I coded- position: relative; top-2%;

Need help!!!

Comment: you should use `float: left` or `float: right` with `50% width`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comment, you should use `float: left` with `width: 50%` to do this.

```
.six.columns {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xLr8x2gr/)**